# Fix max record number in a virtual scrollable grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to fix the max number of records in a virtual scrollable grid i.e. when the pageChange event is fired and I append some 'n' records to the grid, I also want to remove the already existing top 'n' records from the grid so as to keep the overall number same.

Subsequently, I also want the pageChange function to be called when the user scrolls back to the top of the grid.

Overall aim is to keep the memory usage low. How do I achieve this/Is it even possible? I am using angular 4.

Please also feel free to suggest other grids that I can use instead of Kendo if you feel that other grids are better suited to this use-case.

Comment: Do you have to use virtual scrolling? I would suggest using paging instead.

Comment: Yes, it is a business requirement to use virtual scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed possible in the Angular 2 version of the grid. DeBounce ensures to call the Load function after every time you scroll.

Even normally, the Load function is called as soon as the limit of the data argument has been reached, which can be controlled. I am still searching for an example that works with angular-4.